# conditional DirectoryIndex based on IP address, using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, conditional-statements

I've got this in `httpd.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost xx.xxx.xx.xxx>
    Options All +ExecCGI
    ServerAdmin hostmaster@thehost.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain.com
    ServerName  dl.domain.org
    DirectoryIndex dlindex1.html
</VirtualHost>
```

... which is fine (what I need as the `DirectoryIndex` for our 'dl.domain.org' subdomain), *but* now I also need to alter that `DirectoryIndex` based on IP address, using `.htaccess`.
Is this possible?

Other SO posts are telling me that I cannot set `DirectoryIndex` conditionally.. but instead *have* to use a `RewriteRule`.
If that is true, OK, but what `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule`?
I am pretty noob in Apache, but anyway have tried many things, including (where the actual IPs are those of our 2 devs):

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^111\.222\.333\.444$    [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^555\.666\.777\.888$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^dl.domain.org
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1/dlindex2.html
```

..or even just (as an absolute test):

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^555\.666\.777\.888$
RewriteRule (.*)/dlindex1.html$ $1/dlindex2.html
```

But it seems that whatever I try it just serves up the `DirectoryIndex dlindex1.html` as per `httpd.conf`, as opposed to the `dlindex2.html` I want served up as the default page in that subdomain when a devs IP is calling.

Can any one point me to what I can do to get what I am after? i.e. this: ...to actually, or even just effectively, alter `DirectoryIndex` based on IP address, using `.htaccess`, on the fly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 ways turned out to work for me:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44129/conditional-directoryindex-based-on-ip-address-using-htaccess

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/32727/conditional-directoryindex-based-on-ip-address-using-htaccess

e.g.:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^12\.34\.56\.78$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index\.html$
RewriteRule .* /index1.html

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^12\.34\.56\.78$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index\.html$
RewriteRule .* /index2.html
```